# How can we be assure that people with read access to keys, can not also read the ciphertext and vice versa?

Tags: key-management

We have this segregation of duties requirement and don't understand it fully. Is it not always possible, that an employee who is generating keys can also get access to the encrypted messages?

Comment: _how_ are they generating keys, and where?  If you're able to make it so key generation is performed on the remote machine by a pre-set script (and not, say, on a local machine and then sent to any remote machines), then people can't even read the keys in the first place....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could a person who creates encryption keys and therefore has access to them, copies or otherwise, use them to decrypt messages? Yes, but only if they also have access to the message storage.

Simply store the encrypted messages in a location not accessible to the key creation people. Give the message reading people access to only the keys they need.

Segregation of duties should also include segregation of access.